# Zend like with or condition

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I got sql question with where condition:

```
$select->where('(users.user_fname LIKE (?) )','%'.$first.'%');
```

How to put in it OR condition so it would look like:

```
$select->where('(users.user_fname LIKE (?) )','%'.$first.'%');
OR
$select->where('(users.user_fname LIKE (?) )','%'.$last.'%');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html

```
$select
    ->where('(users.user_fname LIKE "%?%")', $first)
    ->orWhere('(users.user_fname LIKE "%?%")', $last)
;
```